# Как я могу проверить не попал ли случайно текст в editText (numberDecimal)?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть editText (numberDecimal) который считает числа (также в этот editText копируются значение  и если в него попадет не цифра   ) сбой гарантирован! 
Как я могу  проверить не попал  ли случайно текст  в editText (numberDecimal)?

```
вот `что приблизительно получается `(0.1669 Max Su)

вот что я нашел if(el4.getText().toString().contains(" "))
```

как это работает?

Comment: проверяется, не содержит ли полученная строка символа пробела. если в строке не будет пробелов, но будут другие символы, то проверка провалиться

Comment: Понял мне нужно выдавать ошибку если в  edit text  будет что то подобное 0.1669 Max Su не должно быть текста

Comment: примеры [проверки содержимого edittext](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.widget.EditText&method=setError) и вывод сообщения о ошибке

Comment: нужно типа такого   if(el4.getText().toString().contains("[a-zA-Z]")) но у меня не работает

Comment: метод contains() не работает с регулярными выражениями, но в примерах по ссылке выше есть проверка через регулярные выражения